Send schedule email when column is modified in Sharepoint Online page or document library - Power Automate
I have a requirement where i would like to send a scheduled email (one or twice a week) notificaton of all files or pages that have been changed in one email.
I don't want to alert then each time there is a change.
Any ideas how this could be achieved using Power Automate

This seems reasonably straightforward.  You could set up a scheduled flow in Power Automate and then call the [Get Items] SharePoint action.  Using the ODATA filter within this action, you could narrow down the items that you want by examining the Modified field.  There are a whole bunch of different ways to create the date boundaries you are looking for i.e. utcNow() and utcNow() mins 7 days.
Once you have your list of items, you can then iterate through them and amend the details that you want to a string variable.  I would construct a HTML table in the process of doing this, as this can then easily be added to the email that you want to sent.
The only real issue I see is if you want to loot=k at multiple different data sources, or complex folder structures.
HTH
mc
